# How to build a Parallax Scroller with Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, html, pixi.js

I'm having a problem with the pixi.js "[Building a Parallax Scroller with Pixi.js: Part 1](http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=5226)" tutorial.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Parallax Scrolling Demo</title>
    <style> 
        body { background-color: #000000; }
        canvas { background-color: #222222;}
        </style>
 </head>
 <body onload="init();">
    <div align= "center">
        <canvas id= "game-canvas" width= "512" height="384"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.0.0/pixi.min.js" ></script>
    <script> 
        function init() {
            stage = new PIXI.Container();
            renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(512,384, {view:document.getElementById("game-canvas")});

            var farTexture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("resources/bg-far.png");
            far = new PIXI.Sprite(farTexture);
            far.position.x = 0;
            far.position.y = 0;
            stage.addChild(far)S

            renderer.render(stage);
        }
        </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I can't get my images to render.

Comment: The link to the tutorial doesn't work

Comment: Now I have a CORS error as well. Is this thing on??

Comment: Tutorial Link: http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/ Under tutorials HTML5 Parallax

Comment: Are you having a problem with a Sublime Text package related to this? If not, I don't think this is a Sublime Text question; as a text editor, it has no bearing on how the browser interprets the code that you write with it.

Comment: I thought it was important to relay as much info as possible.

Comment: How do I debug a CORS error in Chrome?

Comment: It's important to relay the information that is directly related to the problem. If Sublime or Chrome is _causing_ the error then it's directly related. If it happens to be what you typed the file in, or serving it, then no, it's not related to the problem. and tagging it only confuses people.

Comment: Not that the align attribute has been obsolete for many years and shouldn't be used

Answer (score -1):

When constructing files in Microsoft, it is important to go back into Properties-->Security and make sure your permission settings match (for each file).
Additionally, in order to avoid a CORS error it is also important to use Administration settings; Specifically settings in the IIS or Internet Information Services.
Here, you will need to examine and adjust your permission settings.